# Running multiple executables in one window

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio

I am a mechanical engineer and only have basic understanding of programming so I am looking for somebody to guide me in the right direction. My question is that I have a bunch of flow meters that connect to the computer via RS232 connection. The flowmeters came with an application software(an executable file) that is used to display the flow going through it. Anyhow, when I am using multiple flowmeters at the same time, I have to open multiple instances of the same application.

I know I can create a batch file and specify the path to open all the executables in one shot but I was wondering if there is a way I can create some kind of desktop app or a user interface which I could link to the already existing .exe files and have them open and display everything in one window.

I will appreciate any help regarding where I can start to look or find resources to do such a thing.

Thanks

Comment: What you want can be done. But Stackoverflow is not the right forum for your question. Because SO works best with fairly specific questions that can be answered in one or a few paragraphs. Your question is too broad (create a GUI) and probably  requires a long tutorial style answer. So it is thus not suitable for the SO format.

Comment: Perhaps the flowmeter manufacturer can help... but I am curious as to how many RS232 ports your desktop PC has.

Comment: @WeatherVane The best the flowmeter manufacturer could do was to provide me with a desktop app and told me to open multiple instances of the app for every flowmeter. So I am trying to make it a little user friends so I open only one app and can see everything in one instance. As for your curiosity about the number of RS232 ports, I only have one RS232 port but we bought a 16 port RS232 to Usb adapter. [Link](http://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Serial-Cards-Adapters/~ICUSB23216F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be non-trivial programming-wise to have a bunch of instances of an EXE all display their output in the window of another program.

What would be much easier would be to create a script to start all the instances of the EXE and position and size each window to achieve the look you want. The main difference between this and all EXEs within a Window is that they won't all go to foreground/background when you click a flow app or another (non-flow app). If you can live with that difference then...

I suggest using Powershell (PS) if you don't know a suitable scripting language already. [Here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527) is a PS script that set the size/position of a window. Another possibility is [WASP](https://wasp.codeplex.com/) which has a lot more GUI automation capabilities (which might make it more daunting).

After selecting and learning how to use one of the scripts above you'd then write a script that starts each instance of the flow app, using the right serial port, and other other appropriate command line arguments. Then you'd position and size the window of the flow instance you just created. You'd do that once for each instance. So the script you write is just a straight list of instructions: no loops, no data structures, etc. Which means you'd have a minimal amount of PS to learn.

You can create another script to terminate all the instances of the flow app, if you want. Similarly you could create a third script to minimize the windows of each instance. And another to restore the windows. Etc. In essence your controller app is a set of PS scripts. Which, if you got ambitious, could be turned into a GUI app, again using PS.